# Rails caches_action to json content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, 
`render json: User.all` with a caches_action for :index returns content type text/html. How do I force it to application/json?

Before:

```
def index
 render json: User.all.to_json
end
```

Returns json with Content-Type: 'application/json'

After:

```
caches_action :index

def index
 render json: User.all.to_json
end
```

Returns json with Content-Type: 'text/html'. So technically it's a json string in html.

Comment: What content type does it have without `caches_action` - can you show the  relevant controller action code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do that, according to the documentation is to declare your route as a json route in your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: alternatively you'd just need to make sure that you were adding `.json` to the end of the URL (like `http://your.app.com/users.json`), as this is how rails 'magically' determines what content type to return if none is specified.